# How to filter row based on the drop down we choose?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I do created a table and two drop-down filter for the table. The first drop-down filter is Year which has the option of "All", "2023", "2022" and "2021". So, when I pick "2022", the row "2022" is shown. The second drop-down filter is for the Type (excluding Year) which has the option of "All", "ASB" and "ASB 2". So, when I pick "ASB", the column "ASB" is shown.

[image: Table All]

[image: Table Filter 2023]

The problem that occurs here is that the second filter is not functioning. Well, when I pick "ASB", the table not trigger to shown only "ASB" column for all year (if I pick "All" for Year).

Code:

```js
const yearSelect = document.getElementById('year-select');
const typeSelect = document.getElementById('type-select');
const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

function filterTable() {
  tableRows.forEach((row) => {
    const yearCell = row.querySelector('td[data-heading="Year"]');
    const typeCells = row.querySelectorAll('td[data-heading^="ASB"]');

    const yearFilter = yearSelect.value === 'all' || yearSelect.value === yearCell.textContent;
    const typeFilter = typeSelect.value === 'all' || Array.from(typeCells).some((cell) => cell.dataset.heading === typeSelect.value);

    if (yearFilter && typeFilter) {
      row.style.display = '';
    } else {
      row.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

yearSelect.addEventListener('change', filterTable);
typeSelect.addEventListener('change', filterTable);

filterTable();
```

```css
.table-container {
  padding: 32px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.filter-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.filter-container label {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.filter-container select {
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.table-container h3.table-heading {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, orange, yellow);
}

.table-container table {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
  padding: 24px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

th {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255)!important;
}

.table-container table thead tr {
  background: #162536;
  color: #fff;
}

.table-container table td,
.table-container table th {
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-container table tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 580px) {
  .table-container table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  .table-container table td {
    display: block;
  }
  .table-container table td::before {
    content: attr(data-heading) ": ";
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="table-container">
    <div class="filter-container">
      <label for="year-select">Year:</label>
      <select id="year-select">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="2023">2023</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
      </select>

      <label for="type-select">Type:</label>
      <select id="type-select">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="ASB">ASB</option>
        <option value="ASB 2">ASB 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>ASB</th>
          <th>ASB 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-heading="Year">2023</td>
          <td data-heading="ASB">%</td>
          <td data-heading="ASB 2">%</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td data-heading="Year">2022</td>
          <td data-heading="ASB">%</td>
          <td data-heading="ASB 2">%</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td data-heading="Year">2021</td>
          <td data-heading="ASB">%</td>
          <td data-heading="ASB 2">%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
```

So, how to fix it?

I do expect that the drop-down filter for Type will functioning well as for example below (example below is from picture which I edit to show on how do I want the table to show:

[image: P3]

[image: P4]

Comment: For starters, you forgot to actually include any of the `ASB 2` cells in your selection to begin with: `const typeCells = row.querySelectorAll('td[data-heading^="ASB"]');`

Comment: _"So, when I pick "ASB", the column "ASB" is shown."_ - you have not implemented any showing/hiding of _columns_ at all yet, all you are doing is showing or hiding _rows_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform as per i given ,

```js
 const yearSelect = document.getElementById("year-select");
      const typeSelect = document.getElementById("type-select");
      const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

      function filterTable() {
        tableRows.forEach((row) => {
          const yearCell = row.querySelector('td[data-heading="Year"]');
          const typeCells = row.querySelectorAll('td[data-heading^="ASB"]');

          const yearFilter =
            yearSelect.value === "all" ||
            yearSelect.value === yearCell.textContent;
          const typeFilter =
            typeSelect.value === "all" ||
            Array.from(typeCells).some(
              (cell) => cell.dataset.heading === typeSelect.value
            );

          if (yearFilter && typeFilter) {
            row.style.display = "";
          } else {
            row.style.display = "none";
          }
        });
      }

      yearSelect.addEventListener("change", filterTable);
      typeSelect.addEventListener("change", () => {
        let hideColGroup = document.getElementById("hide-col-group");
        let typeSelect = document.getElementById("type-select");
        if (typeSelect.value == "ASB") {
          hideColGroup.innerHTML = `<col span="2" id="hide-col" />
          <col span="1"  style="visibility: collapse"/>`;
        } else if (typeSelect.value == "ASB 2") {
          hideColGroup.innerHTML = `<col span="1" id="hide-col" />
          <col span="1"  style="visibility: collapse"/>`;
        } else {
          hideColGroup.innerHTML = ``;
        }
      });

      filterTable();
```

```css
   .table-container {
        padding: 32px;
        font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
      }

      .filter-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
      }

      .filter-container label {
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-right: 8px;
      }

      .filter-container select {
        padding: 4px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      .table-container h3.table-heading {
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 32px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, orange, yellow);
      }

      .table-container table {
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        color: #222;
        padding: 24px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 15px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-top: 16px;
      }

      th {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
      }

      .table-container table thead tr {
        background: #162536;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .table-container table td,
      .table-container table th {
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .table-container table tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
      }

      @media (max-width: 580px) {
        .table-container table thead {
          display: none;
        }
        .table-container table td {
          display: block;
        }
        .table-container table td::before {
          content: attr(data-heading) ": ";
          font-weight: bold;
        }
      }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="table-container">
      <div class="filter-container">
        <label for="year-select">Year:</label>
        <select id="year-select">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="2023">2023</option>
          <option value="2022">2022</option>
          <option value="2021">2021</option>
        </select>

        <label for="type-select">Type:</label>
        <select id="type-select">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="ASB">ASB</option>
          <option value="ASB 2">ASB 2</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <table>
        <colgroup id="hide-col-group"></colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>ASB</th>
            <th>ASB 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td data-heading="Year">2023</td>
            <td data-heading="ASB">%</td>
            <td data-heading="ASB 2">%</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td data-heading="Year">2022</td>
            <td data-heading="ASB">%</td>
            <td data-heading="ASB 2">%</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td data-heading="Year">2021</td>
            <td data-heading="ASB">%</td>
            <td data-heading="ASB 2">%</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
```